# How to plot an array as if the indices i,j were the x,y coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

Hi guys first question here, looked for an answer but could not find anything, I will try to give it my best.

I am currently working on a problem in the field of Computational Physics and I am solving the Navier-Stokes equations numerically using the Finite Difference Method. It`s my first time working with Python (using a Google Colaboratory notebook with Python 3). I am solving the equations for a **grid of points in a two-dimensional plane**. I created this grid **using np.arrays**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 10
data = np.zeros((N,N))
```

and then manipulating it. For example

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        data[i,j] = i
```

which makes the values of the array increase with index `i`. However, if I plot my data-array now using

```
x = np.arange(N)
y = np.arange(N)

plt.contourf(x, y, data)
plt.colorbar()
```

The result of the example:

[image: result]

It shows that the plotted data increases along the y-axis even though my manipulation of the array should make it increase along the x-axis.
I noticed this happens because the indexing of arrays `(i,j)` is different from the standard orientation of x- and y-axis, but how can I plot my data-array as if `i=x` and `j=y`?

Comment: You get the transpose of a numpy array `a` via `a.T`. Maybe note that numpy indexing is consistent with mathematical matrix notation, the first dimension are the rows, the second are the columns. So maybe while you're starting with all of this, think about adopting this standard.

Comment: To follow up on that comment. In your case you would have `plt.contourf(x,y,data.T)` Though I would also encourage you to look into [pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh) and [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow)

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's ndindex function to get the indices based on shape and then unzip the result.

```
x,y=list(zip(*np.ndindex((N,N))))
```

The data is row by column and can be obtained with meshgrid. If you're interested in the same manipulation. You can make the data with meshgrid as

```
dx,dy=np.meshgrid(np.arange(N),np.arange(N))
```

And then plot the dy to get variation in the x axis.